# Slow rendering of tin of large area in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, rendering, arcscene, tin

i am using ArcGIS 10.3.1 and working on TIN generation for entire H.P(India).

I have downloaded  DEM & generated TIN but it is very slow and when I am doing anything the entire TIN starts forming again and it is taking a lot of time. I have tried many options like started working on geodatabase , done some system setting but still the problem exists.

My system is 8 GB RAM and also have dedicated & 2GB extended graphics. I have tried opening in ArcScene for 3D view but it is only processing and after sometime it stops.

I am unable to  do any analysis. I don't know how to proceed.

Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

ArcScene has some [limitations](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000007905), although I think the link I am providing is for x86 systems.
From personal experience you cannot load large TINs(> 1GB) into ArcScene/Desktop and visualize, but you can load them into Pro. I have managed to load 4GB TINs into Pro with around 60 millions nodes. You should know that Pro requires quite a lot of resources.I have 32 GB of RAM, a Ryzen 1700x and a 6 GB 1060 and sometimes it feels it's not enough. 
 
What you can do is to cut the TIN into smaller pieces using [Edit TIN](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/edit-tin.htm) or [Extract TIN](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=fe221371b77940749ff96e90f2de3d10).One alternative would be to use [Decimate TIN Nodes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/decimate-tin-nodes.htm) but you lose on precision here. Another thing I managed to do is to load the TIN directly into the tool you want to use, without prior loading into Desktop/Scene, but this does not work every time.

Comment: hi thanks for replying me back. I can see that my size of tin is about 1.36 GB.May be this will be the reason. I just wanted to know if I want to analyse the elevation data of the entire area in 3D then it is possible in pro? what is the possibility of such analysis in Q GIS. Please suggest.

Comment: Please do not ask new questions as comments. Thanks comments are [discouraged](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) because they clog up the database with chit-chat. Please take the [Tour] to better understand our purpose and policies.